# Design pattern to "toString" a third party object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a third party object which uses the toString method inherited from Java.lang.Object.  This method is pretty useless.  However I can't think of a clean design to override this behavior.  Different approaches below.

1. Subclass and override the toString method.

**The problem**: if any calls internal to the original object call toString and inspect the returned String, they will now break.  I don't want to break the existing object, or assume anything about the cleanliness of the third-party code.

2. Create a StringFactory with a createString method.This method calls toString on all objects other than my third-party object in question, but for my object builds a String in my custom way.

**The problem**: I can neither require that everything gets passed to the createString method and never called toString on directly (this would be ludicrous across a large code base) nor can I easily remember which objects should be passed, because there is custom logic for them.

Does anyone have a design pattern that feels clean?

Comment: Subclassing and providing a `myToString` method and using that in your own code can be a solution depending on what you want to achieve. Would it work?

Comment: About #1 - if they're calling `toString` and depending on its answer for correctness, they have failed at their understanding of the purpose of `toString`.

Comment: @glowcoder yes, that's why I'm suggesting a *new* method, no overriding. Similar to Bohemian's answer but a little more object oriented to my taste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a static method on a util class:

```
public class MyUtils {

    public static String toString(My3rdPartyClass obj) {
        // impl here
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this. Elegant, short, reusable, and free of alterations.

Comment: @glowcoder The other thing about this approach is it avoids class bloat: You can add impls for as many other classes as you wish.

Comment: I feel like this is the same as my #2 in the original question.  Except to are increasing the scope of this class to include all Utilities, which I feel is a mistake, due to a possibly large set of utilities.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it probably is the best way to answer my question as written, and because the use case of wanting to override methods for your own personal use without altering the subclasses behavior probably doesn't extend past 'toString'.

Answer (score 5):

I really like Bohemian's answer.

With that in mind, an OOP way to solve it would be

```
class My3rdPartyClassFormatter {
    private My3rdPartyClass data;
    public My3rdPartyClassFormatter(My3rdPartyClass d) { this.data = d; }
    public String toString() { 
        // impl here
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a variation of the Decorator Pattern? On second thought -- this is a wrapper class.  1+ for the suggestion. And now after 3 votes in this question, I'm all out of votes for the day.

Comment: @Hovercraft yes it's more of a wrapper. I wouldn't consider it a decorator, but I could see the utility of comparing it to a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).  Your invocation handler will intercept all calls to the 3rd party object.  In most cases, it will just pass them through.  However, implement your own toString logic.

```
InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler
{
       private ThirdParty thrd ;

       public Object invoke ( Object proxy , Method method , Object [ ] args ) throws Throwable
       {
             if ( method . getName().equals ( "toString" ) )
             {
                  return "useful string" ;
             }
             else
             {
                  return method . invoke ( thrd , args ) ;
             }
       }
}
```

Comment: Proxies are very powerful but can introduce issues if you're not careful (for example, you may also need to handle the `equals` method).  Also, proxies require a target interface.  Still, +1 as this is a solution in some cases.